# Rails 5: Assets + Bower + Bootstrap Sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

*There are already similar questions on SO, but not enough clear responses to understand the following issue.*

My goal is to setup Rails 5 with Bootstrap using Bower.

Using Bower I installed Bootstrap in the the folder:

```
vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-sass
```

Then, I updated **initializers/assets**:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

Then I added the **gem 'sass-rails'** to **Gemfile** and updated **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The assets for JS seem to be working well: if I load **http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js**
I can see that the Bootstrap JS part has been added there.

The problem is about Sass (SCSS):
I added **bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap** into application.css.scss but with no success:

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
 */
```

in fact if I load http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css I see:

```
/*
 @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
 */
```

(the folder specified on the @import is containing many _*.scss files and a mixins folder)

The questions are:

- Do you have any ideas why this is not working?
- should not I see on **assets/application.css** all the CSS precompiled?

PS:
Any resource to understand the issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the import, so it's outside the `/* .. */`

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/

@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Comment: That won't work as the @import doesn't use Rails asset pipeline.

Comment: thanks @JariJokinen but actually it is working. The Assets pipeline doc says: "If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass import rule instead of these Sprockets directives ".

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the rails-sass is aware of asset pipeline paths.

Answer (score 1):

[Removed misleading instructions to use require instead of import, as I was wrong.]

In addition to the accepted answer, if you look into the `bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets` directory, you'll notice that there is no file `bootstrap.scss` but rather one prefixed with an underscore.

Also, usually it's better to import only modules you actually need from the `bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/` directory instead of the main `_bootstrap.scss` file.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it works as well as @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap". I am wondering actually what is the difference between the 2 solutions.